# Is reinterpret_cast and c-style cast compatible (by C++ standard)?

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

The C++ standards mentions that `reinterpret_cast` is implementation defined, and doesn't give any guarantees except that casting back (using `reinterpret_cast`) to original type will result in original value  passed to first.

C-style casting of at least some types behaves much the same way - casting back and forth results with the same value - Currently I am working with enumerations and `int`s, but there are some other examples as well.

While C++ standard gives those definitions for both cast-styles, does it also give the same guarantee for mixed casts? If library X returns from function `int Y()` some `enum` value, can use any of above casts, without worrying what cast was used to convert initial `enum` to `int` in Y's body? I don't have X's source code, so I cannot check (and it can change with next version anyway), and things like that are hardly mentioned in documentation.

I know that under most implementations in such cases both casts behave the same; my question is: what does C++ standard say about such cases - if anything at all.

Comment: C casting back and forth doesn't always result in the same value... `(float)((int)3.141)` will not give me `3.141` back.

Comment: You can use `static_cast` to convert between ints and enums.

Comment: @Xymostech I mean only types that behave properly under C-style casts. I know that C-style casting modifies values in some cases, but for those cases entire question is pointless.

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually as I just learned, `reinterpret_cast` between int and `enum` causes "invalid cast" error - so it has to be `static_cast`. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ defines the semantic of the C cast syntax in terms of `static_cast`, `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`. So you get the same guaranteed for the same operation whatever syntax you use to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

`reinterpret_cast` can only be used for specific conversions:

- Pointer to (sufficiently large) integer, and the reverse
- Function pointer to function pointer
- Object pointer to object pointer
- Pointer-to-member to pointer-to-member
- *lvalue* expression to reference

plus (conditionally) function pointer to object pointer and the reverse. In most cases, the converted value is unspecified, but there is a guarantee that a conversion followed by its reverse will yield the original value.

In particular, you can't use `reinterpret_cast` to convert between integer an enumeration types; the conversion must be done using `static_cast` (or implicitly, when converting an unscoped enumeration to an integer type), which is well defined for sufficiently large integer types. The only possible problem is if the library did something completely insane such as `return reinterpret_cast<int&>(some_enum);`

A C-style cast will perform either a `static_cast` or a `reinterpret_cast`, followed by a `const_cast`, as necessary; so any conversion that's well-defined by `static_cast` is also well-defined by a C-style cast.

Answer (score 1):

No, `reinterpret_cast` is **not** equivalent to a C style cast. C style casts allow casting away const-volatile (so it includes the functionality of `const_cast`) not allowed in `reinterpret_cast`. If `static_cast` is allowed between the source and destination types, it will perform a `static_cast` which has different semantics than `reinterpret_cast`. It the conversion is not allowed, it will fallback to `reinterpret_cast`. Finally there is a corner case where the C cast cannot be represented in terms of any of the other casts: it ignores access specifiers.

Some examples that illustrate differences:

```
class b0 { int a; };
class b1 { int b; };
class b2 { int c; };
class d : public b0, public b1, b2 {};
int main() {
   d x;
   assert( static_cast<b1*>(&x) == (b1*)&x );
   assert( reinterpret_cast<b1*>(&x) != (b1*)&x ); // Different value
   assert( reinterpret_cast<b2*>(&x) != (b2*)&x ); // Different value, 
                                                   // cannot be done with static_cast
   const d *p = &x;
   // reinterpret_cast<b0*>(p);                    // Error cannot cast const away
   (b0*)p;                                         // C style can
}
```

Comment: There is also `const_cast`, so error you commented out can be "fixed" using it. Anyway, I think you misunderstood me. My question was not if those can be exchanged in a given line of code, but if value casted to another type by one of them (say C-style) is guaranteed to give the same value when casted-back to original type using the other (any of `_cast` C++ operator).

Comment: @j_kubik: I understood the question, maybe I was not clear in the answer. `reinterpret_cast` is **not** equivalent to C cast, neither is `static_cast`, or `const_cast`. In the cases where they are equivalent, the inverse cast can be applied, in some other cases the inverse cast is even implicit, **but** you cannot blindly do `reinterpret_cast` back for precisely the examples I provided (in particular the second and third asserts. To the question: *Can I cast back ignoring what the original cast is?* the answer is **No, you cannot**

Comment: If I know both original and casted type that some opaque libX casted between, then I know what kind of cast they used: C-style works in predictable ways, and what you mentioned above limits their freedom to use `_cast` casts, usually leaving only one option(at leas only sane one, `reinterpret_cast` between pointers is possible but usually used only if `static_cast` is not possible). Having that cleared, I want to know if I can cast back without knowledge which of above two was used. I am not interested in generic case if cast-incompatibility, because I operate on already known types.

Comment: @j_kubik: I am not sure you realize what you are asking, the answer is still the same: **there are cases where if you do the incorrect cast it will not do the right thing**. That is the answer to *"I want to know if I can cast back without knowledge of*. **Without knowledge**, you don't know what the library did, you don't know what you need to undo. From a practical point of view you can *assume* and it will probably work, **but** there is no guarantee at all.