# Can I convert a pointer to member function to a char array and back using reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, c++11, reinterpret-cast

I have some code that looks like this:

```
char member_data[16];

template<typename T>
void set(void (T::*member)(void)) {
    memcpy(member_data, (char*) &member, sizeof(member));
}

template<typename T>
void (T::*)(void) get() {
    void (T::*member)(void);
    memcpy((char*) &member, member_data, sizeof(member));
    return member;
}
```

<sup>In the full context, I can be sure that `set` always uses the same type as the following `get`.</sup>

Can this be safely rewritten to use `reinterpret_cast`?

### Edit:

Does this code do the same thing as above?

```
char member_data[16];

template<typename T>
using member_func = void (T::*)();

template<typename T>
void set(member_func<T> member) {
    reinterpret_cast<member_func<T>&>(member_data) = member;
}

template<typename T>
member_func<T> get() {
    return reinterpret_cast<member_func<T>&>(member_data));
}
```

[Seems to work](http://ideone.com/UKWszH)

Comment: this seems risky `memcpy(member_data, (char*) &member, sizeof(member));` e.g. if T is char

Comment: @claptrap: T cannot be char, since `char::*` cannot exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version you have in your edited part is not valid: you can't access an *arbitrary* `char` array as any other type. It may be possible to achieve something like this in a valid way by using `std::aligned_storage<..>` instead of a plain `char` array.

If `member_data` is declared as

```
std::aligned_storage<sizeof(member_func<T>), alignof(member_func<T>)>::type member_data;
```

or (essentially equivalently)

```
alignas(member_func<T>) char member_data[sizeof(member_func<T>)];
```

then your `reinterpret_cast<..>` approach should actually work. Instead of the template parameter dependent `sizeof` and `alignof` expressions, you can try using any fixed `member_func<some_class>`. It is highly unlikely that an implementation has different size or alignment requirements for pointers to member functions of different classes. If you want to be really safe use static asserts to check.

> Can this be safely rewritten to use reinterpret_cast?

Other than what is described in your edit, you can directly cast a member function pointer, like `reinterpret_cast<SomeType>(member)`, only, if `SomeType` is also a pointer-to-member type. So you **can** choose one pointer-to-member function type as "generic member function pointer storage", if all you do with that value is to convert it back to the original member pointer type.

You can't convert a pointer to member into a pointer to object (or vice versa).

In both cases your code is unsafe as is, because it will overrun the `member_data` buffer, if `sizeof (void (T::*)()) > 16`.

And by the way: the first code example already *does* use `reinterpret_cast`: The old-style cast to `(char*)` from `void (T::**)()` already is equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast` ;-)

Comment: I'll probably stick a `static_assert` in there to verify that `sizeof (void (T::*)()) <= 16`. Also, there was a typo in `get` - that shouldn't ever overflow.

Comment: @Eric: in your originaly code, `<=` is not enough, as you use two different sizes in `memcpy`. And the `reinterpret_cast` approach can be made to work, if you establish sufficient alignment for the storage. See the first part of my edited post.

Comment: @JoergB `static_assert` is unnecessary; just use `alignof(void (void::*)())` and `reinterpret_cast` to `void (void::*)()` on the RHS.

Comment: @ecatmur: You can't declare pointers to members of `void`. With an arbitrary (possibly incomplete) class type instead you can do it. But then you need two `reinterpret_cast`s for each of `get` and `set`. In theory the alignment and size could probably differ between pointers to members of different classes, but it would be a strange implementation that did this.

Comment: While my reinterpret cast [does work](http://ideone.com/UKWszH), I had completely missed the problem of alignment. If I ignore it, should I expect a compiler error at some point in the future, or a runtime error?

Comment: With `reinterpret_cast<...>` you are telling the compiler that "I know what I'm doing", so it is very unlikely that there will be a compiler error. It depends on the platform and implementation, if you violate alignment constraints - and if you do the behavior is undefined. On some platforms alignment violations simply slow down your code on others they cause runtime crashes (typically something like "bus error").

Comment: Ah, thanks. One more thing - I'm seeing some [weird behaviour](http://ideone.com/5lqraD) with `aligned_storage`, where it allocates twice as much memory as I'd expect.

Comment: If `aligned_storage` is used with defaulted second template parameter, it will use the maximum alignment value an object of the given size requires. It is also the case that `sizeof(aligned_storage<anysize, alignmentx>) >= alignmentx`, because `sizeof` includes padding that would be needed to use that type in an array (where each element needs to meet alignment constraints). If your implementation has a type of size <= 8 for which `alignof` is 16, that would explain your result.  Maybe some implementations simply use the maximum alignment requirement they have for any type as default.

Comment: @JoergB: Regarding your comment _"And by the way: your code already does use reinterpret_cast: The old-style cast to (char*) from void (T::**)() already is equivalent to a reinterpret_cast"_, that's **not** entirely true.  See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13385611/69998).

Comment: @JoergB: Yep, that seems to be what is happening - the alignment defaults to 16

Comment: @Void: in this case it **is** equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`